# Ruby Qt documentation

Tags: qtruby

Where can I find the documentation for ruby qt?
(ex. rdoc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use the `rbqtapi` program to find which functions have been implemented, but it almost identically matches the Qt library. The only main difference is objects like QPushButton are actually named Qt::PushButton.

Answer (score 5):

There is also this http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Ruby